# Member variable needs parameters for constructor

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I'm trying to include a member variable in the class I write,

MyClass.h

```
#include <SomeClass.h>
Class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(int par);
        SomeClass B;
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "SomeClass.h"
MyClass::MyClass(int par){
    B=SomeClass(par);
}
```

However `SomeClass` takes variables for its constructor, so the above code yields `no matching function for call to "SomeClass::SomeClass()"`

What should I do here?

**Update:**
Seems like member initializer list is the way to go, but how if I want to use an array of `SomeClass` objects? So MyClass.h becomes:

```
#include <SomeClass.h>
Class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(int par);
        SomeClass B[2];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use member initializer list

```
MyClass::MyClass(int par) : B(par)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks @billz! It works :) Is it possible to use array here? say `B` is `B[2]`

Comment: @XunYang: Yes, but only in C++11: `B{par, par}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite get what you want, but you can get what you need.  To provide array access to the set of objects, create an array of pointers

```
Class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int par);
    SomeClass B0;
    SomeClass B1
    SomeClass* B[2];
```

Then initialize the pointers in your constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int par) :
  B0(123), B1(456)
{
    B[0] = &B0;
    B[1] = &B1;
}
```

This is clearly tedious for more than a small number of objects, but fine for anything you are likely to do on a microcontroller.
Now you have an array of object pointers that can be used as you need:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
    B[i]->foo();
}
```

Note that you are consuming additional memory for a pointer to each object.

Comment: Thanks @jdr5ca! This seems to be the best way to go, although I decided not to fiddle too much with pointers this time :). I assume pointers are not going to take the same memory as an actual object?

Comment: The microcontroller has 16 bit address space, so a pointer is 2 bytes.  In the example above, total of 4 bytes.